# pg_restore -F d -j {n} internal steps and estimation of time

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I'm running a looooong `pg_restore` process of a database with 70 tables and 800Gb. The process is taking 5 days now. I'm monitoring some aspects of the process to evaluate how long will it take but I've some things missing and this is why I'm asking.

I run `pg_dump` with parameters `-F d -j 10` the dump took about 12 hours. I noticed each one of the 10 threads took responsibility of a single table from start to end. After ending of processing a single table, the same process (`pid`) started with another table not taken by another process.

Running `pg_restore` is taking much longer (5 days and still working). The main reason is that I'm restoring to a NAS external drive mounted using `nfs` and that drive is very slow compared to a local hard drive. This is NOT a problem, I'll migrate the information back from the NAS to the original hard drive once I format the hard drive again and install the new operating system.

I'm doing two things to monitor progress:

- In a separate terminal I launch `du -sh /var/lib/pgsql` and evaluate the disk space consumed in the new installation. It has to reach, more or less, the same space the original database was using.
- In a separate terminal I launch `ps -fu postgress` and I see several `pg_restore` processes running. Each one of then linked with another process with this shape `postgress: postress {dbname} [local] {command}` where {dbname} is the database name, and {command} varies. Initially, there was the `COPY` command I think that was used to restore the table content. I also saw some `CREATE INDEX` commands for re-creating the indexes of that table, and now I see `ALTER TABLE` commands, don't know exactly for what.

At this time, all processes are just doing `ALTER TABLE` and the overall used space almost matches the initial space, but the process does not ends (and it is taking 5 days now).

So I'm asking if someone has more experience and can tell me what `pg_restore` is doing with the `ALTER_TABLE` command and if there is any other mechanism to estimate how long will it take.

Thanks!
Ignacio

Comment: Is that the only database in your instance/cluster? If yes, using pg_basebackup and spinning up the target instance based on that might be a lot faster.

Comment: A parallel restore on a slow device is not a good idea. A single process that can do a sequential write while being the only process, can be significant faster than 2 or more processes doing random writes and fighting for resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ALTER TABLE` statements at the end of a `pg_restore` create primary and unique keys as well as foreign key constraints. They could also be attaching partitions, but that is normally very fast.

Look into `pg_stat_progress_create_index` if you have a recent enough PostgreSQL version (you didn't say), then you can monitor the progress of primary and unique key indexes being created.